# List filtering using lambda + filter in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I am finding hard myself to filter a basic need: I have a list and I have to filter it by an value of the items:
My code:

```
list1=[{"a":865,"b":1},{"a":56,"b":6},{"a":995,"b":1,"c":5},{"a":1,"b":42}]
a=filter(lambda x:x["b"]==1, list1)
print a
```

I get the valid output, but if i want to update my filter with a==865 and b==1, i get an invalid syntax error:

```
a=filter(lambda x:x["a"]==865 && x["b"]==1, list1)
print a
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `&&` with `and`.  That should do it!  [The docs (python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)